# $wpdb->prepare() returns NULL or empty on seemingly correct SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, gravity-forms-plugin, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress site where a logged in user completes a form and, upon submission, displays a page where they can choose additional services they can also purchase based on their purchase history. I am using the Gravity Forms plugin.

I'm achieving this by running an SQL query to detect their form submission history, and then eventually incorporating jQuery to display their personalized offers. But I have only gotten this far, I at this point I'm just trying to *echo out the sql query results*.

Here is my code:

**functions.php**

```
// Redirect user to Additional Service Offers page if ..
// .. user has services he/she has yet to purchase..
// AFTER FORM SUBMISSION
add_action('gform_after_submission', 'form_submit_redirect');

function form_submit_redirect() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        // Obtain ID of user currently logged in
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $cur_user_id = $current_user->ID;
        $frm_status = 'active';
        $q = "SELECT 'form_id' FROM wp_rg_lead WHERE 'created_by' = %d AND 'status' = %s";

        // Prepare sql query to retrieve user's past form entries
        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($q, $cur_user_id, $frm_status));
        var_dump($results);
    }
    else { // Re-direct to log in according to current form page
        // This is all working ...
    }
}
```

**Things I have tried:**

- var_dumping the results - **returns empty**.
- Populating an array with the query results and var_dumping the array - **returns empty**.
- Running the SQL statement in phpMyAdmin - **works fine**.
- Passing return method arguments through $wpdb->prepare() - OBJECT, OBJECT_K and ARRAY_A **all return NULL**.
- Various methods in calling $wpdb->prepare() and $wpdb->get_results() respectively.

Help would be appreciated!!

Comment: no. it's not correct. `'created_by'` is a STRING, not a field name.

Comment: Also next time print the errors `$wpdb->print_error();`

Comment: @MarcB 'created_by' is a field name. It's the user ID in the wp_rg_lead table.

Comment: no. it's got single quotes. therefore it's a **STRING**. `created_by` is not the same as `'created_by'`. if you awnt to quote a field name, then go read that dupe. mysql doesn't use single/double-quotes for identifiers. it uses backticks. `\`created_by\``.

Comment: @MarcB Well, that did the trick. phpMyAdmin threw me off when I was trying to run the query there because it automatically puts single quotes around field names when inserting them. Thanks so much for clarifying, now I know! Such a stupid overlook :P

Comment: syntactically the query was valid, because you CAN do `where 'foo' = 'bar'`. it's just a string comparison that always works out to boolean false in this case. but that's a plainly silly/useless query.